# Como salvar os parâmetros de uma função numa variável?

Tags: javascript

Eu quero executar esta função `coord(343,5,6,2,86528,875433, longitude, latitude, 'COORDENADAS');`

Mas eu queria salvar os parâmetros para executar a função depois. Como salvar?

Tentei `var x = 343,5,6,2,86528,875433, longitude, latitude, 'COORDENADAS'`
mas dá erro.

Comment: Como assim você quer chama-la de novo? Você quer executa-la de novo usando os mesmos parâmetros?

Comment: @KaduAmaral Sim, atualizando um ou dois parametros mas usando a mesma base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode acessar o objeto `arguments` da função:

```js
var args; // Variável no escopo global para salvar os parâmetros
function MinhaFuncao(x, y, z, w, k, j){
    args = arguments; // Salva os parâmetros passado
    console.log(arguments);
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = arguments[1];
}
//; Executa função primeira vez
MinhaFuncao(1, 'arroz', 3.14, 'macarrão', true, 'joão', 'picolé', 'maracujá');

// Alterando o terceiro argumento
args[2] = 'Feijão';

// Pode chama-la novamente usando o apply:
if (args != undefined)
   MinhaFuncao.apply(this, args); 
   // Primeiro parâmentro é o contexto, 
   // o segundo é o array de argumentos
```

```html
<p id="log"></p>
```

Retorno do objeto `arguments`:

```
Arguments[8] {
  0: 1
  1: "arroz"
  2: 3.14
  3: "macarrão"
  4: true
  5: "joão"
  6: "picolé"
  7: "maracujá"
}
```

Comment: Interessante, contrapondo que não foi necessário salvar separadamente e é possível salvar e editar, obrigado!

Comment: Como `arguments` é um tipo especial, eu recomendaria salvar como array: `args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);`

Comment: Tem algum motivo em especial ou situação que apenas atribuí-lo diretamente seria um problema @bfavaretto?

Comment: É que geralmente não se espera encontrar um objeto tipo Arguments fora de uma função.

Answer (score 2):

Seria assim:

```
var p1 = 343, p2 = 5, p3 = 6, p4 = 2, p5 = 86528, p6 = 875433, 
    p7 = longitude, p8 = latitude, p9 = 'COORDENADAS';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/DeclaringVariable.js).

Note que você tem 9 parâmetros aí, precisa salvar em 9 variáveis. Poderia usar o *array* também, mas acho que é até melhor neste caso que sejam 9 variáveis. A única coisa que deveria mudar em relação ao que eu fiz é dar nomes mais significativos para as variáveis, indicando o que é cada parâmetro.

Você pode achar que não é uma boa solução, mas não vejo uma melhor, apesar de existirem outras criativas. Na verdade não sei porque precisa disto, talvez você nem tenha esta necessidade. Não faz muito sentido fazer isto. É possível que todo o *design* da aplicação esteja errado.

Comment: Sim, acertou, até lhe entendo. Mas é uma requisição que vai pro servidor e foi rejeitada, ou seja eu preciso reenvia-la com os mesmos parametros mas atualizando alguns para que ela nao seja novamente rejeitada, não vejo um problema de design, se tiver solução melhor.. Mesmo assim obrigado!